# iOS Dynamic table view cell height on downloaded image

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using `SDWebImage` library to download images, then I cache them in an `NSMutableDictionary` using the URL as the key. The idea is that the `UIImage` is resized (i.e from 2800x2000, to 280x200) and the `UIImageView`'s height will adapt to it (i.e. height would be 200). Ergo, the cell height should grow respectively.

Inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` I'm having an issue where the returned height is wrong, here's the deal:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static int defaultHeight = 230;

UIImage *image = (UIImage*) [[self images] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]]];
if(!image) {
    NSLog(@"Null returned");
    return defaultHeight;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not null");
    WKZEventsCell *cell = [[self offscreenCells] objectForKey:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        NSLog(@"DEQUEUED");
        cell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [[self offscreenCells] setObject:cell forKey:CellIdentifier];
    }

    WKZEvent *event = [[self eventList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell titleLabel] setText:[event title]];
    [[cell placeLabel] setText:[event title]];
    [[cell pictureView] setImage:image];

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];


    CGSize imageSize = [image size];
    CGFloat imageViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth([[cell pictureView] bounds]);

    CGFloat correctHeight = (imageViewWidth / imageSize.width) * imageSize.height;

    [[cell pictureView] setFrame:CGRectMake([[cell pictureView] frame].origin.x,
                                            [[cell pictureView] frame].origin.y,
                                            imageViewWidth,
                                            correctHeight)];

    NSLog(@"Real: W: %f, H: %f", imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    NSLog(@"Scaled: W: %f, H: %f", imageViewWidth, correctHeight);
    NSLog(@"Url: %@", [event image]);


    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];


    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    height += 1.0f;

    NSLog(@"Height: %f", height);

    return height;
}
```

Basically I'm getting a cell instance for measuring purposes only. The `NSLog()` calls that prints the real size and scaled size, are fine. The issue is that the `height` is always a value like `1044.0` where it should be returning something around `220` (for the example where the image height is scaled down to 200).

I read somewhere that calling `dequeueReusabeCellWithIdentifier:` will result in a memory leak, so that's my first hypothesis but I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you should only use image.size calculate cell's height.

Comment: what are the constraints on your cell?

Comment: You must be getting warnings with that code. When you fix your problem, come over and post your code at Code Review, we'd help you write better code.

Comment: @KudoCC But the cell's height depends also on another 2 labels, besides de image view. how do I calculate it?

Comment: @elio.d the constraints are similar to the accepted answer in  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights, the difference would be that in my case, the height depend on the image

Comment: @duci9y well the only warning I have it's about not having an identifier for the segues initiated directly from view controllers